# Transition timing is not the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make some 3D slider but the transition for style isn't starting the same time:

I want it to look like it is coming and rotating to the center.

As you can see it resizes first and then moves and transforms.

```js
function sasa() {

  var s = document.getElementById('s1');
  s.classList.add('slidef');

}
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(50px) rotateY(-30deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  right: 50px;
}
.slidef {
  transition: width 1s linear 0s, height 1s linear 0s, -webkit-transform 1s linear 0s, right 1.5s linear 0s;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  right: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="sasa()">ssssss</button>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide1" id="s1">sasa</div>
```

Comment: there is no function called `sasa`!

Comment: So the onClick is calling sasa() -- which hasn't been included in your code. Should that be nextSlide() ?

Comment: yeah eyah i just edited

Comment: Only get the perspective in Chrome, but both Chrome and Firefox are showing the transitions happening together (scale/center/ transform).

Comment: For me it starts resizing after finishing that transform and after moving to left. In chrome..

Comment: try to remove `perspective(0px)` from the last css line --> https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/r80uokgv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(50px) rotateY(-30deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  right: 50px;
}
.slidef {
  transition: 1s linear 0s;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  right: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg);
}
</style>
<script>
function sasa() {

      var s = document.getElementById('s1');
      s.classList.add('slidef');

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="sasa()">ssssss</button>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide1" id="s1">sasa</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

OP, I saw you commented that it appears the transitions are still not occurring at the same time. I changed the script block to monitor the changing styles during the transition.

```
<script>
function monitor(e, done) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
    console.log(
            style.width,
            style.height,
            style.right,
            style.transform);
    if (! done.value) {
        new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0))
        .then(() => monitor(e, done));
    }
}

function sasa() {

      var done = { value: false };
      var s = document.getElementById('s1');
      s.addEventListener("transitionend", e => done.value = true, false);
      monitor(s, done);
      s.classList.add('slidef');

    }
</script>
```

The result in the console indicates to me that all the style transitions are beginning and ending together. So I'm not sure what you are seeing. But I'm also not sure I completely understand what you are going for. You can go back to setting individual transition times for each style and tweak them until you get what you want. To do that, define slidef like the following and change the start and delay numbers for each style. What I've shown does the transform first and then the scaling and translation second.

```
.slidef {
  transition: 
    width 1s linear 1s,
    height 1s linear 1s,
    right 1s linear 1s,
    transform 1s linear 0s;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  right: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Yes I just added right .7s it looks better, but what is differenc with ur and mine code when I just added in transition for what changes to look up to?

Comment: But also as you see it is starting transform  after it comes to center(left) and after resize is done.. Can it run the same time?

Comment: The only change I made was to use the same transition time for all properties rather than different times for each. Compare my value for transition in the slidef class versus yours.